# Ormlite OR key in query

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ormlite

I cannot implement `"AND (id = 6 OR some = true)"`

Is it possible to realize "AND (.... OR ....)" in querybuilder?

OrmLite gives me results like OR is general, not part of AND construction.
Sorry for bad English and will be glad any proposals.

> Ormlite

.  I need use in queryBuilder construction like this:

```
>   where().eq( ..., ...).and().eq( ...., .. ).and().eq( ..., ... ).and
> (.... or ....).
```

Someone please help me with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a nested query, which is supported by [QueryBuilder](http://ormlite.com/docs/building-queries) 

Something like this:

```
Where<Account, String> where = queryBuilder.where();
where.or(
      where.and(
      where.eq(Account.NAME_FIELD_NAME, "foo"),
      where.eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "_secret")),
where.and(
      where.eq(Account.NAME_FIELD_NAME, "bar"),
      where.eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "qwerty")));
```

Comment: R4j, thanx. I really read documentation so absently. ( Now query works good.